# python HTTP Client - proxy requests as a GET parameter

Tags: python, proxy, python-requests

Im behind a firewall and need to do all requests in the format of  `http://the-proxy-gateway.set?url=https%3A%2F%2Fapi.stripe.com`.

So I need to pass the desired URL as a GET parameter (and also uri encode the request).

How can I configure a standard Python http client (requests, urllib2 or whatever) to do this?

Comment: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#proxies

Answer (score 0):

I could be missing something but this kind of just seems like a regular `request.get` with `params` set.

This example doesn't work in the sense that the proxy url is fake but if you look at the error message (modified for brevity) the parameter seems to be properly encoded.

```
In[2]: import requests
  ...:
  ...: PROXY_URL = 'http://the-proxy-gateway.set'
  ...:
  ...:
  ...: def proxy_as_get(url):
  ...:     r = requests.get(PROXY_URL, params={'url': url})
  ...:     r.raise_for_status()
  ...:     return r.json()  # ???
  ...:
In[3]: r = proxy_as_get('https://api.stripe.com')
Traceback (most recent call last):
    ...
    Max retries exceeded with
    *****
    url: /?url=https%3A%2F%2Fapi.stripe.com
    *****
    ...
```

Another example:

```
In[2]: import requests
In[3]: PROXY_URL = 'http://the-proxy-gateway.set'
In[4]: params = {'url': 'https://api.stripe.com'}
In[5]: req = requests.Request('GET', PROXY_URL, params=params)
In[6]: prepped = req.prepare()
In[7]: prepped.url
Out[7]: 'http://the-proxy-gateway.set/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fapi.stripe.com'
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, this works as a manual way to do each request through the gateway. However I need to setup the http client (requests in this case) to always use this approach. The reason for this is that the Stripe Python uses the requests client as well and I need it to proxy.

Comment: @JørgenSvendsen Have you tried setting the `HTTP_PROXY` and/or `HTTPS_PROXY` environment variables, [as shown in the docs](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#proxies)? 
Also, it looks like `Stripe Python` has a proxy setting as well, [have you tried setting that](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-python#configuring-a-proxy)? If those don't work then you might be able to monkey-patch `requests.get` using this function above.